# Separate number from a alphanumeric

Tags: shell, unix

I want to remove M from

```
82M
```

how can I do it in a shell script

```
var=82M
```

Wanted value

```
var1=82
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many ways to remove non numeric characters:

```
$ v=82M
$ echo "$v" | tr -cd '0-9'
82
$ echo "$v" | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
82
```

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH's string manioulation:

```
var=82M
var1="${var//[^0-9]*}"
echo "$var1"
82
```

OR using tr:

```
tr -d '[[:alpha:]]' <<< "$var"
82
```